# 3ds "A" button messing up, how to fix?

Tags: new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

I am not sure how it happend but the "A" button messes up, I still responds but it still messed up.

Examples:

In "sims 3 pets" if I press "A" to choose somthing I have to press the button a few times for it to work.

In "mariokart 7" my kart goes slow then speeds up but keeps slowing sometimes and it cancels my drift sometimes.

I tested a few other games and it seems like it is most likely the 3ds/button and not any of the games.

How do I fix the button to make it work properly (without opening up the 3ds in anyway) the "A" button makes it take longer to choose somthing and slows my kart down in mario kart.

Comment: I don't think you can fix it without opening it.

Comment: If you don't want to open it up yourself then your only other option is to send it in for repairs.

Answer (score 1):

Without opening it up, there are a couple of things you could try:

- Try blowing or use a can of compressed air on the button. Use small bursts, don't damage the button
- Use a toothbrush (preferably new and dry - don't put any cleaner on it) and try to reach under the button and clean out any residue
- Use a q-tip with a little bit of alcohol and clean **around** the button. Careful because if you clean over the button, the letter might fade.

Good luck!